# Change Date & Re-Change Program

Tags: windows, batch-file, launch

thank you to whoever gets back to me on this. So I am trying to write a little something that will

- change the date in Windows to show: `4-15-2015`
- launch an `.exe`
- pause for either a minute or a keystroke from the user
- change the date back to what ever the actual date is

I was using a `.bat` file, and I was able to change the date to `4-15-2015`, launch the `.exe`, and use "`pause`" to wait until a Keystroke, then I got stuck with figuring out how to take the original date and change the "`4-15-15`" back to the original date.

My `.bat` looked like this:

```
@echo off
Date 4-15-2015
Start (path To exe)
```

and then I didn't know how to put it back to whatever it was when I originally launched the application. So if I launched it on May 8th I would want to put the displayed windows date back to may 8th, if I launched it on `7-12-15` I would want to put it back to `7-12-15`. Anyone have any ideas? Should I use another lanugage? And if so, how would I write this? I had a thought of reading the initial date and keeping it as a variable... but I don't know how to using a `.bat` file. Thanks to any help.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me (but it depends on the local format of the date):

```
echo %date:.=-%>today.txt
date 07-12-15
echo %date%
date<today.txt
echo %date%
```

or with a variable instead of a textfile:

```
set today=%date:.=-%
date 07-12-15
echo %date%
date %today%
echo %date%
```

Answer (score 0):

Awesome thanks for the help. With a little reformatting here is what I got, and it works flawlessly!

```
@echo off
set $date=%date:~4%
set $date=%$date:/=-%
date 04-15-2015
START C:\Program Files...(to .exe)
PAUSE 
date %$date%
```

Thank you!